# Helm does not upgrade rolebindings

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I'm writing a helm chart to help us provision namespaces for different projets.
The chart is taking care of creating the namespace, serviceaccounts, limits, quotas, volumes and rolebindings.

It's working pretty good so far, except for one point ...

Helm does not seem to update rolebindings if you run a `helm upgrade`.

We want to be able to reapply the chart regulary in order to correct any divergence from the reference point.

Actually, what `helm upgrade` do is creating the correct rolebinding if it doen't exist, but in the case the rolebinding is already present, but with different user/group subjects, it does NOT correct it.

I was able to enforce this by specifiying `helm upgrade --force`. In this case the rolebinding is being recreated, however, I can't use this technique : the `--force` option when used on a namespace recreated the userid of the namespace (sa.scc.uid-range) and then any NFS mounted volume have to be manually "chown" to the new UID ...

I've tried to use the annotation "helm.sh/resource-policy=keep" on the namespace but that does not help.

I'm stuck with these two options :

- use "--force", in that case the rolebindings are recreated accordingly, but namespace UID change which leads to NFS permissions issues
- not use "--force" and the live with the fact that the rolebinding defined in my helm templates may not be the one I need, they can deviate.

A solution would be to split the chart in two parts : one taking care of the namespace creation, and one taking care of the k8s objects inside, but I don't like this that much.

Maybe somebody has a better idea ?

```
---
{{- range .Values.evsEnv }}
apiVersion: authorization.openshift.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: evs-rb-admin
  namespace: {{ $.Values.evsName }}-{{ .name }}
roleRef:
  name: admin
subjects:
  {{- range $.Values.evsGroupAdmin }}
  - kind: Group
    name: {{ . | quote }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- range $.Values.evsUserAdmin }}
  - kind: User
    name: {{ . | quote }}
  {{- end }}
  - kind: User
    name: {{ $.Values.evsRequester | quote }}
---
{- end }}
```

Comment: May not be like for like, but I can see a similar issue being raised here: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6468
Don't see a solution other than using the `--force` flag and/or manual intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add an annotation that will make your`RoleBinding`manifest change each time you run`helm install`?

```
metadata:
    annotations:
        rollme: {{ randAlphaNum 8 | quote }}
```

source: https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments

Comment: Unfortunatelly that doesn't work, even if it's a nice trick that I might use for other things ....
The annotation is added, but the `subjects:` part of the rolebinding is never updated.
Thank you anyway for the suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I could implement was to create a second chart and split my templates between the two charts :

- one chart taking care of the creation of namespaces, which is updated with `helm upgrade`
- one chart taking care of the objects inside the namespace, like rolebindings, serviceaccounts, volumes, ... which is updated with `helm upgrade --force`

Now I have modified my pipeline to work like this and it's what I wanted, however not the most elegant way to do it ...